# Powershell replacing shortcut target

Tags: powershell

can someone please check this script and point me to the right direction. I'm not getting any errors though but script is not working as expected. I'm trying to achieve a shortcut target changed based on logged user.My powershell skills are basic and i'm sure must be missing some logic here:-

```
#$shell = new-object -com wscript.shell
$loguser="username"
$link ="test1.lnk"
$oldtarget=$link.tragetpath 
$oldpath="c:\notepad.exe"
Get-ChildItem  -Filter $link -Recurse
if ($oldtarget -eq $oldpath)
{
$csvfile=Import-csv "c:\test.csv"
$newtarget=$row.newpath
$user=$row.user
(get-Content $csvfile) | foreach-object {$_.$user -match $loguser} | -replace        $oldtarget $newtarget
}
$link.SaveInfo
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain a bit more what your script is supposed to do ?

Comment: hi I'm trying to change shortcut target path based on logged on user. script will run and check logged on user then find if shortcut exist and compare target path if target path is $oldpath then script will import csv file and look for username (logged on user) first row, second row will be new path. Script will replace $oldpath with newpath. Thanks

Comment: This fragment of code can't run. There are mispelling of object properties ("tragetpath"), $row is never defined, $link.SaveInfo comes from nowhere ... Please, give your *actual* code with enough context to run it.

Comment: Hi David I'm quiet limited when it comes to scripting. Task is quiet clear, to change target path based on logged user. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A way better way to modify shortcuts is to get rid of the VBScript shell and use P/Invoke. Take a look at [sample code](http://poshcode.org/2407) in Poshcode. It contains some 1200 lines of code, so I won't copy it here.

Comment: Thanks I would like to stick to VBS or powershell for this task. Can someone there please suggest what to do Thanks

Comment: @Rajni, the code *is* Powershell. It happens to use .Net internally, which is perfectly valid an approach and in some cases the only way to achieve specific goals.

Comment: can u please direct me to the specific script to achieve this task or something closer.

Comment: @david Thanks for pointing error in script.As you can guess from this script this is my second script but I really started enjoying powershell scripting and trying to mold my task around it so I can do more and more scripting good for me. Changes I made                   $oldtarget=$link.targetpath 
    $newtarget=$userobject.newpath
    $user=$userobject.user